Scipy optimize SLSQP: How is the 'ftol' parameter used?
I am wondering how the 'ftol' paramater in scipy.optimize.minimize(method='SLSQP') is used. In the documentation it just says, that it is the precision goal for the value of f, which could mean different things.
I know there is a paper where the original algorithm is explained; you can find it here:
http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2022/02/slsqp-original-paper.html
However, I am not able to find the stopping criterion herein. Scipy provides a wrapper to the algorithm explained in that paper, which, I believe, is written in FORTRAN and not easy to read.
Thank you in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Looking at the code in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.13.0/scipy/optimize/_slsqp_py.py, it looks the ftol parameter is passed as the acc parameter to the fortran SLSQP routine in here: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.13.0/scipy/optimize/slsqp/slsqp_optmz.f
I don't know fortran, but I guess that the termination criteria is defined in this line:
      IF ((ABS(f-f0).LT.acc .OR. dnrm2_(n,s,1).LT.acc) .AND. h3.LT.acc
     *     .AND. .NOT. badlin .AND. f .EQ. f)


This implies that acc is used in multiple ways:

The absolute difference between the current objective function value (f) and the previous value (f0) is less than acc, OR
The norm of some value s (could be the gradient direction of search) is less than acc.
Some value h3 is less than acc. No idea what this is.


h3 is reused for several different things, but in this context, it is the sum of all constraint violations. So one of the conditions for termination is that the sum of all constraint violations must be less than acc, and the other conditions you mention must be satisfied.
